# How can I check through a string array of roles and return the most senior role?

Tags: c#

The following code returns an array of roles for my user:

```
var userRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
```

The possible roles are:

```
public enum RoleType
{
    Default = 10,
    Guest = 20,
    User = 30,
    Admin = 40,
    Super = 50
}
```

How can I make my code check through the userRoles array and return the highest 
RoleType that it can find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var highestRole = userRoles.Max();
```

does what you want.

*(you need to add `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file for this to work)*

**Update 1:** 
Online working sample: http://ideone.com/U1hXK

**Update 2:**

The examples above assume that `userRoles` is an array of `RoleType` values.

If `userRoles` is an array of `string`s representing role types, then we need to parse these values first. The code now becomes:

```
var highestRole = userRoles
    .Select(r => Enum.Parse(typeof(RoleType), r))
    .Max();
```

Online working sample: http://ideone.com/JHHva

Comment: This just checks the string names,orders and gives me the maximum one. It doesn't take into account anything with the Enum and doesn't return an Enum.

Comment: @Anne I've tested the code and it works correctly. Please see the update to my answer for a working sample.

Comment: @Anne if you still have a problem, let me see your code; we will get it to work.

Comment: @Anne I think I realize what the problem is: `userRoles` is a `string[]` and I thought it was a `RoleType[]`. I've updated my answer.